# Error when trying to install pandas in VSC

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I want to install pandas for python in VSC but I always get a lot of errors and the installation seems to get stuck in an endless cycle. I'm using the command `pip install pandas`. The installation starts with the following lines

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.3.3.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... |
```

Versions:
Python 3.10.0, numpy 1.21.2, pip 21.2.4

One of the error says, that Visual C++ 14 is missing. I just installed the current version of the microsoft build tool but it didn't solve the problem. Any hints how I could resolve this errors?

I'm using Win10 at my Microsoft Surface.

The whole error output is

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-rvgfv7r_\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w2edwy2a\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=51.0.0' wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.18.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.2; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.2; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.20.0; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'arm64'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'Darwin'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.20.0; python_version=='"'"'3.9'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'arm64'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'Darwin'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (257 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and (platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin") and platform_machine != "aarch64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and (platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin") and platform_machine != "aarch64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine == "arm64" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environment  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine == "arm64" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environment  Collecting setuptools>=51.0.0
    Using cached setuptools-58.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21
    Using cached Cython-0.29.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl (979 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.19.3
    Using cached numpy-1.19.3.zip (7.3 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0bmyb222_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjwsihokm'
           cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fha7dpr8\numpy_6699d5e9fd8545fb9c1e128fdc00e36e
      Complete output (229 lines):
      setup.py:67: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.19.3 may not yet support Python 3.10.
        warnings.warn(
      Running from numpy source directory.
      setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fha7dpr8\numpy_6699d5e9fd8545fb9c1e128fdc00e36e\tools\cythonize.py:67: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
        from distutils.version import LooseVersion
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
      Cythonizing sources
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      blis_info:
        libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Found executable C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\gfortran.exe
      Using built-in specs.
      COLLECT_GCC=C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\gfortran.exe
      COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2020a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
      Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
      Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers 
--with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
      Thread model: posix
      gcc version 6.3.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_info:
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fha7dpr8\numpy_6699d5e9fd8545fb9c1e128fdc00e36e\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_info:
        libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fha7dpr8\numpy_6699d5e9fd8545fb9c1e128fdc00e36e\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fha7dpr8\numpy_6699d5e9fd8545fb9c1e128fdc00e36e\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
        NOT AVAILABLE

      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'      customize GnuFCompiler
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Using built-in specs.
      COLLECT_GCC=C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\gfortran.exe
      COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2020a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
      Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
      Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers 
--with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
      Thread model: posix
      gcc version 6.3.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_clapack_info:
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'      customize GnuFCompiler
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Using built-in specs.
      COLLECT_GCC=C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\gfortran.exe
      COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2020a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
      Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
      Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers 
--with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/mingw630/x86_64-630-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw630/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
      Thread model: posix
      gcc version 6.3.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
        NOT AVAILABLE

      flame_info:
        libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_info:
        libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fha7dpr8\numpy_6699d5e9fd8545fb9c1e128fdc00e36e\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fha7dpr8\numpy_6699d5e9fd8545fb9c1e128fdc00e36e\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        NOT AVAILABLE

      numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
        FOUND:
          language = c
          define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running dist_info
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/  
      ----------------------------------------
  WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/c0/7b3d69e6ee68bc54c97ba51f8c3c3e43ff1dbc7bd97347cc19a1f944e60a/numpy-1.19.3.zip#sha256=35bf5316af8dc7c7db1ad45bec603e5fb28671beb98ebd1d65e8059efcfd3b72 (from https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0bmyb222_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjwsihokm' Check the logs for full command output.     
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.19.3 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 
1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 
1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0rc1, 1.20.0rc2, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0rc1, 1.21.0rc2, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.21.2)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.19.3
```

Comment: I reinstalled the VC build tool but then there was an error, that something went wrong with `wheel` and numpy. I uninstalled `Python 3.10.0` and installed `Python 3.9.7` and the installation and also my code seem to run no.